# How to train a model to identify a specific object from images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I have a collection of images with different sizes of the same insect. Say for example, a collection of images of butterflies with different size, colors and so on.  I want to train a model to know that the collection of images is all butterflies.  My goal is to input an image and tell if the input image is a butterfly or not?

How to do this?  Most of the tutorials on Machine Learning are training with multiple entries. Like Dogs and Cats, then the input is either Dog or Cat.  But in my case, the trained model is only a collection of Butterflies.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, and with good reason. All the model would "learn" would be to classify every image as a butterfly, regardless of the actual content. But surely you do want the classification to be made depending on the image's content, so you do need to throw in some images that do not show butterflies.

Be careful to select images that do not differ from the butterfly images in any other systematic way. For example, if the butterfly images tend to have a darker background, the model would end up "cheating" by using that information instead or in addition to what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the problem or requirement is (or seems to be) - Identify if the picture is that of a butterfly or not.

You'd have two classes - Butterfly and Not a Butterfly. But, to train an algorithm to identify if there's a butterfly in an image, it needs to see images that don't have butterflies and learn features(during the course of training) that characterize a butterfly.

Another precaution to take is have enough sample-images of butterfly and non-butterfly, or ensure you handle imbalanced classes appropriately.

Comment: for the not butterflytrain images , I can just have random photos of not butterfly?

Comment: yeah that will work.. just any image that does not have a butterfly. But ensure properties like size, resolution etc. of all images are consistent.

Comment: My problem is my images are of different sizes. So, I need to resize them first? right?

Comment: Yes you must resize them.

Comment: Arne made a good point on having consistent background characteristics as well between the two classes.